# Laravel migration DB statement different result via migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

Using Laravel on connected to a Mysql database. Executing the following directly on the database works as expected, it sets a unique value for the guid.

However, when run in migrations using DB:Statement it sets the guid column to identical values.

```
UPDATE report_files SET guid=REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '');
```

Interested to hear any thought on why this might be?

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL the DB::Statement produced? I believe Laravel will isolate the `REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '');` bit resulting in the same value being used for all records.

Comment: Unfortunately not that. Checked the output and the query was exactly the same.

Comment: What if you tried with `DB::unprepared` instead of `DB::statement`  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-unprepared-statement